# Assign global variable to a function's local variable

Tags: python, global-variables

I want to loop over some global variable `i` and each time compile a new function that uses the instantaneous value of `i`. I can then use each of these functions in future, independent of the current value of `i`.

The problem is I can't find a good way to make the global variable `i` stay local within the namespace of the function. For example:

```
i = 0

def f():
    return i

i = 1

print(f()) #Prints 1, when I want 0
```

I found one solution but it seems very clumsy:

```
i = 0

def g(x):
    def h():
        return x
    return h

f = g(i)
i = 1

print(f()) #Prints 0 as I wanted.
```

Is there a better way to do this, maybe some kind of decorator?

Comment: Something doesn't sound quite right. It might require redesigning the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Python functions are objects, you can set an attribute on them:

```
i = 0

def f():
    return f.i

f.i = i

i = 1

print(f()) # Prints 0 as you wanted
```

or:

```
for i in range(5):
    f.i = i
    print(f())
```

Note that an argument would do the same.

Comment: That's a nice idea, but it doesn't quite work in my context. If I were to now append `f` to some list each time within a loop and then execute any member of the list at a later point, I just get the latest definition of `f` again.

Comment: Take no offence but it sounds like there is a flaw in the design. It sounds very complicated!

Comment: Just as tip: putting functions in a list is rare in Python. One of the beauty of this language is mapping.